# How to get page access token

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I create app in facebook and page in my profile. In "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" section I don't select any option because I want only post text to facebook page (maybe this is problem?).
I have this code:

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'myappid'
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'myappsecret'
FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID = 'myprofileid'

oauth_args = dict(client_id     = FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                  client_secret = FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
                  scope         = 'publish_stream',
                  grant_type    = 'client_credentials'
                  )

oauth_response = urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' + urllib.urlencode(oauth_args)).read()
```

oauth_response looks good

but when I run:

```
resp = urllib.urlopen('https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?'+oauth_response).read()
```

I get error:

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to post on page wall some text when, for example, I click button on my website (Django).

UPDATE:

Ok, I get the pages data in json. I parsing it and I get page_access_token, but when I call this:

```
attach = {
  "name": 'Hello world',
  "link": 'http://linktosite',
  "caption": 'test post',
  "description": 'some test'
}

facebook_graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
try:
    response = facebook_graph.put_wall_post('', attachment=attach)
except facebook.GraphAPIError as e:
    print e
```

I get error: "The target user has not authorized this action"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is basically asking about the same problem, and the answer seems to be what you're looking for: [(OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096261/oauthexception-2500-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-informatio)

Answer (score 0):

If the page_access_token is correct, I guess you (the page admin) have not yet granted permission for your facebook application to post message to facebook page.

Check facebook login function in client side, whether you ask enough permission, the scope option should be 'mange_pages publish_stream photo_upload...' depends on your requirement, rather than only 'mange_pages'